# Bedeutung von "aufs Zuträgliche beschränkt"

Tags: meaning

> Anders als das Tier, dessen Wissensdrang der Instinkt leitet und ***aufs Zuträgliche*** beschränkt, ist die menschliche Neugier ungerichtet.

Was bedeutet "aufs Zuträgliche beschränkt" in diesem Satz?

Comment: zuträglich == gesund

Comment: Das, was ihm von direktem Nutzen, also hilfreich ist.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Zuträglich (veraltend) = nützlich.

Das Tier (behauptet der Text) versucht nur dann Wissen herauszufinden, wenn es davon einen Vorteil hat, z.B: unmittelbar an Futter gelangt. Der Mensch dagegen kann ruhig dasitzen und plötzlich unmotiviert von der Frage ergriffen werden: "Wie funktioniert eigentlich eine Fahrrad-Gangschaltung?", obwohl er dieses Wissen wahrscheinlich niemals selbst anwenden wird. Diese Neugier zeigt nur der Mensch (oder jedenfalls glauben wir Menschen das gerne).

Comment: Würde ich auch sagen. Das Tier ist geleitet von seinem Instinkt zu überleben und versucht herauszufinden wie es an Futter gelangt (z.B. im Winter). Des Menschens Neugier hingegen kann auch vom seinem Urinstinkt abschweifen indem er sich wie oben zB. die Frage stellt wie eine Fahrradgangschaltung funktioniert und sich dieses Wissen aneignet.